# Trying to display image with JSF Primefaces

Tags: java, jdbc

So I have to display an image from my database with primefaces p:graphicImage,
but I'm getting some trouble.
This is my code:

```
FileOutputStream o = new FileOutputStream(new File(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/")+"\\tmp\\userimage.jpg"));
o.write(rs.getBytes("foto"));
foto = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes("foto")), "image/jpg");
```

The first 2 lines are ok. My code creates the right file with the bytes.
Then I use the exact same bytes from the database and this

```
ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes("foto"))
```

returns null.

In jsf I just have

```
<p:graphicImage value="{bean.foto}" />
```

Anyone have any clue?

Comment: Your tagging is waaaaaay off. Please learn to narrow down problems.

Comment: Which database and which JDBC driver? BTW: Why can't you just do `byte[] bytes = rs.getBytes("foo")` and use the resulting array twice?

Comment: Yes, I can create the variable. But that doesn't change the problem. It is a MSSQL Server server. The jtbc is fine. Everything works, but it doesnt create the picture.